# sql can not work within Session_start() in another page

Tags: php, mysql

Session is used in my project. After log in successfully, session_start() is called in my login.php page. And then it will go to another page:repair_device.php. In repair_device.php,

```
isset($_SESSION["admin"])&&$_SESSION["admin"]==true //this can pass
```

and  alert("testInDR") can be showed correctly. But sql did nothing.

If I choose log on directly in repair_device.php, for example:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=xxx' , 'xxx' , 'xxxx');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, true);
```

sql= "select * from hpc_repairdevice order by datetime desc" works fine.

Here is the code of login.html

```
<form class="login" action="index.php" method="post">
<span>account:</span><input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
<span>password:</span><input type="password" name="password"/><br /><br />
<span>verificationCode:</span><input type="text" name="code" /><img id="code" src="create_code.php" alt="another" style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align:middle;" onClick="create_code()"/><br /><br /> 
<input type="submit" style="margin-left:35%" value="logon" /><input type="reset" value="" />  </div> 
</form>
```

Here is the code of index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_GET['log_out']) && ($_POST['code'] != $_SESSION['code']))
{
    echo "wrong verificationCode！<br />" . "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=index.html'>";
}
if(!isset($_GET['log_out']))
{
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
if($user!=null & $pwd!=null)
{
    try
    {
        $conn=new PDO('mysql:host=x.x.x.x;port=3306;dbname=hpc',$user,$pwd);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "faile<br />".$e->getMessage()."<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=index.html'>";
    }

    if($conn)
    {
     $_SESSION["admin"]=true;
    $stas = $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS);
    .....
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "window.location.href='http://xx.xx.xx.xx/repair_device.php'"; 
    echo "</script>";  
    .....
     }
 }
}
?>
```

Here is the code of create_code.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//create pic
header("Content-type: image/png");
.....
$_SESSION['code'] = $verifyCode;     //stor verification code in session
......   
?>
```

Here is the code of repair_device.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 ......
</head>
<body>
  <?php 
   session_start();
  // $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=xxx' , 'xxx' , 'xxxx');
   //$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, true);
   $admin=false;
   if(isset($_SESSION["admin"])&&$_SESSION["admin"]==true)
   {    
   alert("testInDR");   
   $sql = "select * from hpc_repairdevice order by datetime desc";
   ......
   $sel=$conn->query($sql);
   ......
   }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose session id should be passed to repair_device.php, but I don't know how. Who can help me ?

Comment: Why have you commented out your SQL connection? That doesn't pass from one page to the next just because you have an active session. In `repair_device.php` you are trying to `$conn->query($sql)` but `$conn` has not been defined.

Comment: @Luke, I don't want to use account and password to connect DB each page

Comment: @Luke, $conn is defined in index.php with session. is it right?

Comment: Why not create a seperate file containing the connection and simply include the file on each page you require the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database connection isn't passed with the session. One popular way is to have a DB bootstrap file that is included at the head of any page that needs access to the database (Or an autoloader).

```
<?php //index.php, repair_device.php
require_once('db.php');

//rest of page
```

And in the db page you setup your connection (and probably start the session)

```
<?php // db.php
session_start();
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=xxx' , 'xxx' , 'xxxx');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, true);
```

Then the result that would be rendered by PHP would be

```
<?php // index.php
session_start();
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=xxx' , 'xxx' , 'xxxx');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, true);

//rest of page
```

Including the connection on any page that needs it simply requires the one line of code.

Comment: ，username and password are stored in session, and db.php can fetch them in session when connect DB?

Comment: Yes, you could do it that way.